# Is there something wrong with my knapsack

Tags: c, algorithm, dynamic-programming, knapsack-problem

I have a knapsack sort of problem wherein, My constraints are that

1. Maximum money can not be exceeded
2. Input array of cost and weight,  ie cost of item i and weight of item i
3. Maximize the weight.

My Input and Output are supposed to be of the following nature

> 3 4   //3 is the number of different Items, 4 is the maximum money, next three lines show cost and weight
>
> 2 1   // cost and weight
>
> 2 2   // cost and weight
>
> 3 5   // cost and weight

Output of the above would be `5`

Below is my solution, the `codechef` says I am getting a wrong answer, can anyone help me what could be the possible cause for that?

Apart from that, is there something wrong with my approach and can I do any better. I looked up the solution from [**here**](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamic-programming-set-10-0-1-knapsack-problem/) and it seems to me that I have got most of it correct.

Thanks.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int max(int a,int b){
    return a > b ? a : b;
}

int findOutput(int maxMoney,int index,int numOfItems,int *cost,int *weight, int **output){
    if(index >= numOfItems)
        return 0;
    if(maxMoney < cost[index])
        return 0;
    if(output[maxMoney][index] != 0)
        return output[maxMoney][index];
    int a = findOutput( maxMoney-cost[index],index+1,numOfItems,cost,weight,output) + weight[index];
    int b = findOutput(maxMoney,index+1,numOfItems,cost,weight,output);
    output[maxMoney][index] = max(a,b);
    return output[maxMoney][index];
}

int main(){
    int outputFinal = findOutput(maxMoney,0,numOfItems,cost,weight,output);
}
```

Comment: If your manual testing is producing wrong results, you should debug and fix your algorithm. If your testing produces the expected answer, then you should think of the critical test cases that may cause wrong answer.

Comment: @Desolator Yeah, but am I doing it right? Because I've always been intimidated of knapsack problems, and I wanted to know if I was on the right track? Thanks.

Comment: @Kraken I am not sure why you are doing it recursively instead of iteratively in an imperative language such as C. Any special reason?

Comment: @amit I don't understand that? What is wrong with using recursion? I thought that you could use either recursive or iterative without worrying about much. (Recursive will take more time because of the function calls, but that's it I guess?)

Comment: @Kraken There is nothing wrong - it is just not how it is done usually. In imperative languages, usually an iterative solution is prefered unless there is a good reason to use recursion (shorter/more readable code) - but that's really not a must. Just wanted to know why you chose recursion here over iteration.

Comment: @amit TBH, I wrote down the algo on paper, and as it turned out I wrote down a recursive one this time and hence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem in the code seems to be :-

```
 if(maxMoney < cost[index])
        return 0;
```

here you are returning that no items after current item cannot fit in the knapsack but there might be a item that has cost smaller than `maxMoney`.

Remove the above statement and do following modification :-

```
int findOutput(int maxMoney,int index,int numOfItems,int *cost,int *weight, int **output){
    if(index >= numOfItems)
        return 0;
    if(output[maxMoney][index] != -1)
        return output[maxMoney][index];
    int a = 0;  
    if(maxMoney >= cost[index]) {
     a = findOutput( maxMoney-cost[index],index+1,numOfItems,cost,weight,output) + weight[index]; }
    int b = findOutput(maxMoney,index+1,numOfItems,cost,weight,output);
    output[maxMoney][index] = max(a,b);
    return output[maxMoney][index];
}
```

Check only while calculating a if maxMoney is greater than or equal to cost of item so that there is a chance to include the item else that case will have zero value.

**Note :-** Dont use zero as sentinel values for memoization try negative (-1) because there can be cost of zero but negetive is impossible.